# How to show correct Time on DateTime axis (Primary axis) of Line chart after loading data from API response using SFChart in Xamarin forms?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, linechart, syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

Time on DateTime axis (Primary axis) of Line chart showing incorrect time after loading data from API response using **SFChart in Xamarin forms**.

I am using ***SFChart - Line chart*** to show graph having time on x-axis and values on y-axis.
I want to show 24 hours data on graph.
I am getting date time and values from API response.

Before loading data I can see correct time on DateTime-Axis as shown in below image.

[image]

I have set ***IntervalType*** as ***Hour*** and ***Interval*** as ***1*** for DateTime-Axis (Primary axis)

but after loading data, time on DateTime-Axis is repeating 12AM, 4PM and 8AM as shown in below image.

[image]

I am sharing my code so that you will get clear idea what I have done and is there anything wrong in my code.

Xaml.cs

```
<Frame HasShadow="False"
               x:Name="outframe"
               CornerRadius="{OnIdiom Phone=15,Tablet=25}"
               Padding="0"
               OutlineColor="#ffffff"
               BackgroundColor="#4A4541"
               WidthRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=320,Tablet=600}"
               HeightRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=450,Tablet=475}"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               IsClippedToBounds="True">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#4A4541">
                <Label Text="GRAPH"
                       FontFamily="{StaticResource PrimaryFontBold}"
                       TextColor="White"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="0,50,0,0"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="{OnIdiom Phone=16,Tablet=22}"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                <sfcharts:SfChart HeightRequest="200"
                                  WidthRequest="300"
                                  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                  BackgroundColor="#4A4541"
                                  AreaBorderColor="White" AreaBackgroundColor="#4A4541">

                    <sfcharts:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>

                        <sfcharts:DateTimeAxis IntervalType="Hours" Interval="1"  LabelRotationAngle="90" >
                            <sfcharts:DateTimeAxis.LabelStyle> 
                                <sfcharts:ChartAxisLabelStyle LabelFormat = "hh:mm tt" TextColor="#FDDFBD">          
                            </sfcharts:ChartAxisLabelStyle>          
                        </sfcharts:DateTimeAxis.LabelStyle>
                    </sfcharts:DateTimeAxis>

                    </sfcharts:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>

                    <sfcharts:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>

                        <sfcharts:NumericalAxis  Minimum="0"
                                                 Maximum="60"
                                                 Interval="10" >
                        <sfcharts:NumericalAxis.LabelStyle> 
                                <sfcharts:ChartAxisLabelStyle TextColor="White"> 
                            </sfcharts:ChartAxisLabelStyle>          
                        </sfcharts:NumericalAxis.LabelStyle>
                            <sfcharts:NumericalAxis.MajorGridLineStyle>
                                <sfcharts:ChartLineStyle StrokeColor="#bae1f2"/>
                            </sfcharts:NumericalAxis.MajorGridLineStyle>
                            </sfcharts:NumericalAxis>
                    </sfcharts:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>

                    <sfcharts:StackingLineSeries x:Name="MyLineChart"
                                                 XBindingPath="Key"
                                                 YBindingPath="Value" ItemsSource="{Binding LineData}"
                                                 ListenPropertyChange="True" StrokeWidth="1" Color="#FDDFBD" >
                        <sfcharts:StackingLineSeries.DataMarker>
                            <sfcharts:ChartDataMarker MarkerWidth="2" MarkerHeight="2" ShowLabel="False" ShowMarker="true" MarkerBorderColor="#bae1f2" MarkerBorderWidth="2" MarkerColor="White"/>
                        </sfcharts:StackingLineSeries.DataMarker>
                    </sfcharts:StackingLineSeries>
                </sfcharts:SfChart>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
```

Codebehind.cs

```
RViewModel rViewModel;
 public RRGraph()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rViewModel = new RViewModel();
        BindingContext = rViewModel;
    }
```

Model.cs

```
public class ChartData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<LineChartData> DataPoints { get; set; }
}

public class LineChartData:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public LineChartData(string key, double value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Key = key;
    }

    private double value;

    public double Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    private string key;

    public string Key
    {
        get { return key; }
        set
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(value);

            value = dt.ToString("hh:mm tt");
            key = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Key");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

}
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public class RViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ChartData ChartData { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<LineChartData> LineData
    {
        get { return lineData; }
        set
        {
            lineData = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(LineData));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public RespiratoryViewModel(string roomId)
    {
        LoadData();
    }

    public async void LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
    //API call
            ChartData = await AppClass.DataManager.GetRR();
            LineData = ChartData.DataPoints;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Crashes.TrackError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I am struggling with this. Not getting what is exact issue.
Any hint for this?

Comment: I haven't used SFChart, but does each DataPoint have a DateTime? If so, have you verified that those DateTimes are all within one 24-hour period? The symptom looks like they cover several days.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve does each DataPoint have a DateTime? - Yes and all are within 24 - hour period

Answer (score 0):

I tried and I got answer for this so sharing here. Issue is DataType used for Key.

I am getting date time in string format and values in double from API response.
I had kept that Key as string only instead of that it’s datatype should be DateTime.
So I have added one parameter DateValue of datatype DateTime in LineChartData Model.

```
public DateTime DateValue { get; set; }

    public LineChartData(string key, double value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Key = key;
        DateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(Key, "hh:mm tt", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
    }
```

And in xaml set that DateValue to XBindingPath.

```
<sfcharts:LineSeries x:Name="MyLineChart" XBindingPath="DateValue" YBindingPath="Value" ItemsSource="{Binding LineData}" ListenPropertyChange="True" StrokeWidth="1" Color="#FDDFBD" >
                        <sfcharts:LineSeries.DataMarker>
                            <sfcharts:ChartDataMarker MarkerWidth="2" MarkerHeight="2" ShowLabel="False" ShowMarker="true" MarkerBorderColor="#bae1f2" MarkerBorderWidth="2" MarkerColor="White"/>
                        </sfcharts:LineSeries.DataMarker>
                    </sfcharts:LineSeries>
```